# cant get $templateCache to work

Tags: angularjs

Im using [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) to create a module with all my templates. This works fine and I get a module like this:

```
angular.module("starter.templates").run(["$templateCache",
  function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("searchmachines.html",
        // searchmachines.html content
    );
    // etc.
  }
]);
```

But when I try to include this in my app I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter.templates' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument

In my index.html head I have this:

```
<head>
    /* other stuff */
    <script src="templates/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
</head>
```

and in my app.js I got this:

```
angular.module('starter', [
  'ionic',
  'starter.controllers',
  'starter.services',
  'starter.filters',
  'starter.templates'
])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    window.location.href = '#/app/maincategories';
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.showmachine', {
      url: "/showmachine",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/showmachine.html",
          controller: 'ShowMachinesCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  //more routes...
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/searchmachines');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If indeed you have it like this in your app `.run([$templateCache, function($templateCache) {...}])` you should pass the first argument as a string: `.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {...}])`

Comment: Your template name in the `templateChange.put` should be same as `templateUrl` in the angular route. In your case, templateUrl should be `searchmachines.html` in the angular ui route.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problem was that, by default, gulp-angular-templatecache isnt making a standalone module. I totally missed that... By just passing the option: `standalone:true` everything works:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('./www/templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('templatescache.js', { module:'templatescache', standalone:true, root: './templates/' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/templates/'));
});
```

and then in app.js just add the dependency:

```
angular.module('starter', [
  'ionic',
  'starter.controllers',
  'starter.services',
  'starter.filters',
  'templatescache'
])
```

Comment: A couple other points to maybe save you some time.  First, (obvious i know but i still missed it) you have to load the templatescache.js file in your html before your main module.  Second, i had to look into the actual template file to see what name to call my template by.  Unlike the example on the Angular website, i had to call my template like this:  <div ng-include=" 'js/templates/mygrid.html' "></div>

Comment: Thank you.  This was a huge headache